# How can I make a if and else-if statement in jQuery for is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

What can I solve this problem with if-else? I like to do "**if this and this clicked before**" or "**this and this clicked before**" then do something. Look to the bottom of the code.

```
$("#sjf").click(function () {
        $("#sjftable").show();
        $("#fcfstable").hide();
    });

    $("#fcfs").click(function () {
        $("#fcfstable").show();
        $("#sjftable").hide();
    });

    $("#rr").click(function () {
        $("#sjftable").show();
        $("#fcfstable").hide();
    });

    $("#srtf").click(function () {
        $("#fcfstable").show();
        $("#sjftable").hide();
    });

$("#berechnen").click(function () {
    if ($("#fcfs, #srtf").data("clicked")) {
                for (let i = 1; i <= anzahlProzesse; i++) {
                    let cpu = $("#prozess" + i).val();
                    cpuLaufzeit.push(cpu);
                }

                for (let i = 1; i <= anzahlProzesse; i++) {
                    let ak = $("#akzeit" + i).val();
                    ankunftszeit.push(ak);
                }
            } else if ($("#sjf, #rr").data("clicked")) {
                for (let i = 1; i <= anzahlProzesse; i++) {
                    let cpu = $("#prozess" + i).val();
                    cpuLaufzeit.push(cpu);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: no clue what you mean by clicked before.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something you don't need an IF.

```
$("#fcfs, #srtf").on('click') {
```

is an event Listener that is triggered when the click is registered / detected.

So anything you want to happen when there is a click, just put inside the onclick function

```
$("#fcfs, #srtf").on('click')) {
     // DO SOME STUFF HERE
}
```

Comment: It shows me an error at the last brace. It says ";" expected.

Comment: @volkanbi just fixed the jQuery in my answer.  If you have a link to live test where I can see / access what you're working with that would help also.